# display non-editable text in JavaFX with different CSS styles

Tags: css, text, javafx, word-wrap

Some text display in resizable AnchorPane. It may be Label or Text (not editable). In text may be bold (fat) words, for example. How to implement it? Text in Label or Text may be only in one style. When I link bold word with other text as two different Labels, I have problem with text wrapping (.setWrap(true)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer) TextFlow use for this.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm#CHDEEAFG